# Java - Stacks - checking if 2 numbers of the stack equal 100

Tags: java, arrays, stack

I have to check the sum of which 2 values in the stack equal 100 and print out the indecis and the numbers. I have made this possible using arrays but i can't get it to work using stacks. Please help me. I have wrote the following until now and it doesn't give me the right output.

```
import java.util.Stack;

public class 2 {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    int x = 100;
    Stack stack=new Stack();
    Stack tempStack=new Stack();
    stack.push(new Integer(20));
    stack.push(new Integer(53));
    stack.push(new Integer(41));
    stack.push(new Integer(38));
    stack.push(new Integer(28));
    stack.push(new Integer(47));
    stack.push(new Integer(70));
    stack.push(new Integer(30));
    stack.push(new Integer(80));
    stack.push(new Integer(400));
    stack.push(new Integer(3));
    stack.push(new Integer(20));

    tempStack = (Stack) stack.clone();
    for (int i=0; i<stack.size(); i++) {
        tempStack = (Stack) stack.clone();
        int value = (Integer) stack.pop();
        if (!stack.isEmpty()) {
            for (int k=0; k<tempStack.size(); k++) {
                int tmp = (Integer) tempStack.pop();
                if ((value + tmp) == x) {
                    System.out.println("Indices " + i + " & " + k + " with values " 
                            + value + " & " + tmp);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

The following is my array based solution:

```
public class 1 {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    int x = 100;
    int [] array = {20,3,400,80,30,70,20,47,28,38,41,53,20};
    for (int i=0; i<array.length; i++){
        int temp1 = array[i];
        for (int k=1; k<array.length; k++) {
            int temp2 = array[k];
            if ((temp1+temp2)==x)
                System.out.println("Indices " + i + " & " + k + " with values " 
                        + temp1 + " & " + temp2);
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Basically Stack are used for grammar checking for programming languages (in compilers ) and for some service policy implementations such as LIFO.In you case Stack in not the best data structure.

Answer (score 4):

As a [`Stack`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Stack.html) is a [`Collection`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html) it implements [the `toArray(T[])` method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#toArray%28T%5b%5d%29) so you could use that to convert your stack to an array and use your working array solution.

However, you will have the problem that there is no autoboxing for arrays.  Autoboxing automatically converts between primitive types and objects which means, for example, you can add `int` values directly to your `Stack` without creating `Integer` objects, as the compiler does this for you:

```
Stack<Integer> stack = new Stack<Integer>();
stack.push(20);
stack.push(53);
```

However, the compiler won't convert between `int[]` and `Integer[]` so you'd have to do:

```
Integer[] array = stack.toArray(new Integer[stack.size()]);
```

And using `Integer[]` would be a chore.

So the easiest thing to do is this:

```
int[] array = new int[stack.size()];

for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
  array[i] = stack.get(i);
}
```

Creating an array once will be more efficient than repeatedly cloning and emptying a Stack.

(Although if this is a homework question intended to teach you how to use stacks this might not be the best approach!)

Answer (score 1):

Little change in tour logic, dont take `stack.size()` in loop, it decrements at each loop iteration so u iterate only half loop

```
int stackSize = stack.size();
    for (int i=0; i<stackSize; i++) {
        tempStack = (Stack) stack.clone();
        int value = (Integer) stack.pop();
        if (!stack.isEmpty()) {
            int tempSize = tempStack.size();
            for (int k=0; k<tempSize; k++) {
                int tmp = (Integer) tempStack.pop();
                if ((value + tmp) == x) {
                    System.out.println("Indices " + i + " & " + k + " with values " 
                            + value + " & " + tmp);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

The index of the second stack is probably not correct as when you clone the initial stack inside the loop, it is smaller each iteration.

i.e.

```
stack = {25,50}
stack.clone => {25,50}
stack.pop => 25
stack.clone => {50}
thus, if 50+50== 100 the indicies found would be i=1, k=0 instead of 1,1...
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code seems to give the right combination of Numbers, but it fails to give the right combination of Index.

This is because you are calling `pop` function which removes an item from a Stack thereby decreasing its size by 1. Hence the Index you get, is the index as compared to the Stack's size at that instant.

Instead I would suggest, to use `peek()` or `get(int index)` function to read the values. I have updated your example with `get(index)` without cloning the Stack...hv a look...

```
import java.util.Stack;

public class Class2 {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    int x = 100;
    Stack stack=new Stack();
    Stack tempStack=new Stack();
    stack.push(new Integer(20));
    stack.push(new Integer(53));
    stack.push(new Integer(41));
    stack.push(new Integer(38));
    stack.push(new Integer(28));
    stack.push(new Integer(47));
    stack.push(new Integer(70));
    stack.push(new Integer(30));
    stack.push(new Integer(80));
    stack.push(new Integer(400));
    stack.push(new Integer(3));
    stack.push(new Integer(20));

   // tempStack = (Stack) stack.clone();
    for (int i=0; i<stack.size(); i++) {
       // tempStack = (Stack) stack.clone();
        int value = (Integer) stack.get(i);
        if (!stack.isEmpty()) {
            for (int k=i+1; k<stack.size()-1; k++) {
                int tmp = (Integer) stack.get(k);
                System.out.println("Value"+value+" tmp "+tmp+"Stack size"+stack.size());
                if ((value + tmp) == x) {
                    System.out.println("Indices " + i + " & " + k + " with values " 
                            + value + " & " + tmp);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: I tried your way but i don't know I get only 3 outputs. Using the array I get many more values as output.

Answer (score 1):

This is an unnatural use of a stack (want to know how you'd do this in 'stack-oriented' Forth?  You'd use an array.) , so it's only right that you're struggling.  That said, just use your array solution after implementing these stack operators:

1. DEPTH , which returns the number of elements on the stack.
2. PICK, which returns the element at an index into the stack.

If you're permitted to use them, java.util.Stack inherits both: `.size()` and `.elementAt()`

Answer (score 1):

Issue with your stack base solution is in this line. 
int value = (Integer) stack.pop();
 once you pop first element it will disappear from the stack